# How do I use regex in grep to match multiple lines and only get the last matched set?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pcre

I have a file with some statistics like this

```
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-01 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 32
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.fff.aaa.ggg | 20
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL: 52% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-02 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.aaa.bbb | 42
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.bbb.aaa.zzz | 10
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.zzz.xxx | 21
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.sss.ggg | 5
2023-01-02 01:00:00 TOTAL: 78% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```

and I would like to cut out the last set of statistics (in the example above it would be the last 6 lines). As you can see, the amount of lines for each section can change, but the first and the last line stay constant. I was thinking about using:

- "TOTAL" as an anchor point to grab the first and the last line of the wanted block of text
- (?s) mode to match all lines in between those two

I ended up with this regex `(?m)^.*?TOTAL(?s).*?(?m)TOTAL.*?$` and to use it in Linux, I used this command to get the wanted output using `-P` regex extension for grep (I haven't had much luck with `-E` regex extension)

```
tac con.log | grep -Po "(?m)^.*?TOTAL(?s).*?(?m)TOTAL.*?\$" -m1 | tac
```

which resulted in this correct output

```
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```

as expected, however this was in my testing environment which uses an old grep version `2.5.3` and when I tried it on my other machine running on Rocky Linux 9, which uses grep version `3.6` I am not getting any match. Considering this regex worked also when testing at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), I believe this might be a nuance of a newer grep. Is there anything special these newer versions of grep require for a regex like this to work or is there any other way how to get this result (ultimately, it will be used in a bash script)?

Comment: Does it have to be `grep`? Seems like it would be easier in `perl` or `awk`.

Comment: on your Rocky Linux 9 machine, are you running it inside a script or directly on the console? have you checked for quoting errors caused by env differences? perhaps `'` for the regex?

Comment: Please change `cut out` in `I would like to cut out the last set of statistics` to either `print` or `remove`, whichever it is you mean (which I now think is `print` but originally thought was `remove`).

Answer (score 3):

With Perl,<sup>†</sup> one way

```
perl -0777 -wnE'$r = $1 while /(^[0-9\s:-]+TOTAL.+? TOTAL.+?$)/smxg; say $r' file
```

or

```
perl -0777 -wnE'say for /.*( ^[0-9\s:-]+ TOTAL.+? TOTAL.+?$ )/smxg' file
```

This does capture and assign all such records, or matches the whole file, until it gets to the last one, but one has to go over the file; the approach from the question makes three passes over the file.  We can process backwards if performance is an issue, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74504336/4653379) for example. See the performance effect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566399/4653379).

Altogether I'd recommend a short script instead.

Not sure why `grep` does what you show; I'd imagine that the above regex should work, even slightly simplified using grep's conventions.

---

<sup>†</sup> In the question as originally posted by the OP there was a `perl` tag.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -zPo '(?s).*\n\K.*TOTAL .*?TOTAL:.*?\n' con.log
```

This works with 3.7. Seems to mostly work with version 2.20 (appends an extraneous newline). It is likely to be inefficient with huge input files.

I suspect the reason your regex that works at regex101 is failing when used with grep is that grep applies the regex to each line of input in turn. So a regex that tries to match multiple lines at once is always going to fail.

---

With tac and awk, to avoid reading the entire file:

```
tac con.log | awk 's+=($3~/^TOTAL:?$/); s>1{exit}' | tac
```

`s` starts as zero/false. Each time a start or finish line is found, it is incremented. When non-zero, the line is printed (default action). When both start and finish lines have matched (`s==2`), we abort.

Assumes only well-formed records in the log. Allows for unrelated data interspersed between statistics records.

If the file could end with a partial record (that should be ignored), there is:

```
tac con.log | awk '
    !s && $3=="TOTAL:" { s=1 }
    s;
    s && $3=="TOTAL" { exit }
' | tac
```

If the log file contains no unrelated data (just a list of complete statistics records), then only the termination condition needs to be tested:

```
tac con.log | awk '1; $3=="TOTAL"{exit}' | tac
```

---

Assuming that number of lines of output will never exceed some threshold (here 1000), there is also a straightforward tac and (GNU) grep solution that works whether or not there is a partial final record:

```
tac con.log |
grep -A1000 -m1 'TOTAL:' |
grep -B1000 -m1 'TOTAL ' |
tac
```

Answer (score 2):

or just do it the ultra lazy way :

```
echo '
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-01 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 32
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.fff.aaa.ggg | 20
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL: 52% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-02 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.aaa.bbb | 42
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.bbb.aaa.zzz | 10
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.zzz.xxx | 21
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.sss.ggg | 5
2023-01-02 01:00:00 TOTAL: 78% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed' |
```

---

```
mawk 'BEGIN { RS = ORS = " consumed\n" } END { print }'   
                                                      — or even -
gawk 'BEGIN { RS=(ORS=FS=" consumed\n")"$" } $0=$NF'
```

---

```
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```

Answer (score 1):

The key observation with your data is you want the data from the *last* occurrence of `TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION` in your input dataset. You can use greedy matching to achieve that

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $data = <<EOM;
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-01 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 32
2023-01-01 01:00:00 class.fff.aaa.ggg | 20
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL: 52% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-02 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.aaa.bbb | 42
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.bbb.aaa.zzz | 10
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.zzz.xxx | 21
2023-01-02 01:00:00 class.xxx.sss.ggg | 5
2023-01-02 01:00:00 TOTAL: 78% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
EOM

$data =~ s/.+           # Do a greedy match
           (?=          # non-capturing group lookahead
              ^         #     Start of a line
              .+?       #     non-greedy match
              TOTAL\sMEMORY\sALLOCATION\sCONSUMPTION # literal string
            )           # end of lookahead
            //smx; # allow . to match newline & ^ to match start of line

print $data;
```

running that gives

```
$ perl try.pl 
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```

That can all be condensed into a one-liner

```
cat your data | perl -e 's/.+(?=^.+?TOTAL\sMEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION)//sm'
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a simple Awk script.

```
awk '/TOTAL MEMORY/ { p=$0; next }
  p { p = p ORS $0 }
  /TOTAL:/ { result=p; p="" }
  END { print result }' file
```

This implements a simple state machine where we collect all the lines in the current entry into a string and then at the end print out the (last) collected string.

In some more detail, recall that Awk runs the script on each incoming line (or, more broadly, input record) at a time. When we see the first regex, we start collecting items into `p`, and skip the rest of the script for this line. On subsequent lines, as long as `p` is nonempty, we add lines to it, separated by `ORS`, the output record separator (defaults to newline) and then when we reach an input line which matches `TOTAL:` we stop collecting, and copy the currently collected `p` into `result`. Finally, the `END` block runs after we reach the end of the input stream, and we print whatever string we last collected into `result`.

In addition to being portable way back to the original AT&T Unix, this is also easy to understand and modify; the regular expressions are trivial, and the overall logic is reasonably simple and obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/TOTAL /{rec=$0; next} {rec=rec ORS $0} END{print rec}' file
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep with tail will do the job:

```
$ grep TOTAL: file -B6 | tail -n6
2023-01-01 01:00:00 TOTAL MEMORY ALLOCATION CONSUMPTION:
2023-01-03 01:00:00 COMPONENT | USAGE (%)
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.yyy.zzz | 10
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.xxx.zzz.aaa | 20
2023-01-03 01:00:00 class.zzz.aaa.bbb | 30
2023-01-03 01:00:00 TOTAL: 60% out of 100% allocated memory consumed
```